# What version/release of Lua and external libraries are used in Redis?

Tags: redis, lua

What version/release of Lua is used in Redis or how can I find it?

And what about the libraries? cjson, cmsgpack, bitop, etc.

Comment: Lol - you're answering your own questions now, good one though.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Yeap, SO encourages: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Just my two cents to help drive adoption :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Lua

- Lua 5.1.4 from Redis 2.6.0 up to 2.6.12
- Lua 5.1.5 since Redis 2.6.13

There seem to be [no plans](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2843#issuecomment-154341308) to upgrade Lua any further.

The Lua version can be verified on the [Lua.h file at antirez/redis](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/deps/lua/src/lua.h#L20).

### Lua BitOp

Bitwise operations on numbers. [API](http://bitop.luajit.org/api.html)

- Version 1.0.2 since introduced in Redis 2.8.18.

### Lua CJSON

JSON support for Lua. [API](https://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html#_api_functions)

- Version 1.0.3 from Redis 2.6 up to 2.8.17
- Version 2.1.0 since Redis 2.8.18

### Lua cmsgpack

[MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) protocol implementation for Lua. [API](https://github.com/antirez/lua-cmsgpack#usage)

- Version 0.3.0 from Redis 2.6 up to 2.8.17
- Version 0.4.0 since Redis 2.8.18

It has been multiple times since, including security fixes in Redis 4.0.10, without incrementing the version number though.

### Lua Struct

Basic facilities to convert Lua values to and from C structs. [API](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/struct/)

- Version 0.1 from Redis 2.6 up to 2.6.9
- Version 0.2 from Redis 2.6.10 up to 4.0.9
- Version 0.3 since Redis 4.0.10