# How to do contains search in Redis?

Tags: asp.net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am new to the Redis cache implementation. 
I want to search value in all the keys.
The values may or may not be nested collections of list.
What command should I use this to search data?
https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/6802

I am implementing the same in .net core.
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to search inside a hash key as in the screenshot, you can use [`HSCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/hscan) to traverse all the fields of the hash, this returns the value as well. Then test for the value client-side. Or, you can move this logic to a [`Lua script`](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to do it Redis-server-side.

If you want to search in all the keys, consider the following:

- You will need to traverse the whole keyspace, key by key, using [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan).
- Depending on the type, perform the search inside the key.
- Sets and sorted sets can be searched with SSCAN and ZSCAN for values, using `MATCH` option.
- For all other types, you need to do the search by your own.

Again, you can implement the above in a Lua script for a more efficient implementation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462457/how-can-i-get-all-of-the-sets-in-redis/59564727#59564727) can get you started.

Comment: I have used the following command to get all the values. HSCAN users:hash 0 MATCH user:*. But in my case I will have nested collections. See the image, I would have countries collection inside the object. How would I traverse to that and find the value

Comment: You can look at installing [RedisJSON](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/), or do it in Lua, using [Lua CJSON](https://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html#_api_functions) to look inside the value. The CJSON library is already available in redis, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822193/what-version-release-of-lua-and-external-libraries-are-used-in-redis

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if you are using C# StackExchange.Redis. Note that the server Keys command will use SCAN if the Redis version supports it (available since 2.8.0).

```
    public RedisKey[] GetKeysByPattern(string pattern)
    {
        var keyList = new List<RedisKey>();
        var servers = _redisConnection.GetServers();

        // search across all servers for keys
        foreach (var server in servers)
        {
            if (!server.IsConnected) continue;

            // default db (-1)
            var keys = server.Keys(-1, pattern);

            if (!keys.Any()) continue;

            keyList.AddRange(keys);
        }

        return keyList.ToArray();
    }
```